# SQL Query "Select latest record where active flag = 1"

Tags: sql

I need help with a SQL Query.  I would like to query a VersionInfo table to pull the latest record where ActiveFlag = 1.

The latest record might not have a activeflag = 1, which I do not want to pull.

In the example below I would expect to pull (3456, 02/20/2019, 1)

Example:

```
GUID         DATE           Active Flag
-------     -------         -----------  
12345        01/15/2019          1
23455        06/28/2019          0
34564        02/20/2019          1
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Column DATE's data type?

Comment: Please provide also what SQL query you already tried (see [mcve]). In order to get only 1 resulting record you need some kind of **limiting** which is database-dependend (thus you're asked for __DBMS__). And to get _latest_ we need __date/time-ordering__ for column named `DATE`, so its **data-type** as well as DBMS is asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what to do when there are multiple rows for the latest 'active' date, the following query will return all rows for that date:

```
SELECT GUID, Date
FROM YourTable
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM YourTable WHERE active_flag = 1)
```

HTH

Comment: I would like to only the single row that has the latest date and active_flag = 1

Comment: @AndrewCobb first of all, you'd better to share your DBMS(`MySQL`,`Postgres`,`SQL Server`,`Oracle` etc.) with us, as asked above ...

Comment: @Barbaros Ozhan - I'll get the queries posted that I have been using that is not working..Thanks!!!

Comment: @AndrewCobb I suppose I asked for a different thing :)

Comment: Can return an active_flag = 0 row, if it has the same date as the latest active_flag = 1 row.

Comment: @jarlh Good remark! Thus the answered query should be extended by condition `AND active_flag = 1` on the (top/parent/main) WHERE clause. Also note that in order to retrieve _latest_ the MAX-aggregation function only works for DATE-types.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that is specific to SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1
    [GUID]
    , [DATE]
    , [Active Flag]
FROM
    VersionInfo
WHERE
    [Active Flag] = 1 
ORDER BY
    [Date] DESC
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

some database support `limit`

```
select * from table_name where active_Flag=1
order by date desc limit 1
```

Comment: I think you should provide some more explanation with your answer.  Explain what `limit` is, and what it does and why it solves the problem.